# Reiniciar winodws form en c# luego de inactividad

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Es posible que los valores de mi form windows (digase labels, textbox, picturebox, datagrids) se borren o regresen a su valor null luego de que haya pasado cierto tiempo y de ser posible cómo o cuál es el método para poder lograr esto?

Y si alguien tiene un pequeño ejemplo de que hay que hacer se agradece también pero cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lo que planteas se puede usar System.Windows.Forms.Timer. En el siguiente ejemplo luego de 10 segundos se borra una caja de texto (este comportamiento se define en el manejador del timer (timer1_Tick). Se detiene con un Stop sobre la instancia del Timer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private void setTimer()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

            t.Interval = 10000; // Especificas el tiempo que queres en milisegundos. En este caso le puse 10 segundos
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            t.Start();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setTimer();

        }

    }

}
```

Saludos y espero sea de tu utilidad.

Comment: funcionó excelente, muchas gracias!